# Permanently remove Skype icon from taskbar

Tags: windows-10, skype

I'm using Skype 7.25.0.106 on Windows 10 Enterprise.

I'd like the Skype icon to disappear from the taskbar when I'm signed in. The disabling of the setting in "Tools > Options… > Advanced > Advanced settings > Keep Skype in the taskbar while I'm signed in." doesn't survive a restart of Skype. How can I permanently leave it unchecked?

Comment: I have no problem with Skype in Startup. I just don't like to have the icon in the taskbar.

Comment: Does this help? https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA11055/how-can-i-remove-skype-from-the-windows-taskbar

Comment: The option "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" is not checked.

Answer (score 2):

The best is to right Click on its icon of the task bar and click unpin from task bar and if it doesn't work then your go to the task manager, by right click on the task bar and selecting task manager,then you click on the fourth option, startup and disable Skype from start up.

Comment: The icon is not pinned to the taskbar (of course). I'd like to have Skype start with Windows, why disable it?